# Find the shortest length of a chord passing through a point inside the circle.

Tags: geometry

The point $C = (1, 2)$ lies inside the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 9$. What is the length of the shortest chord of the circle through $C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The shortest chord is perpendicular to OC, where O is the origin. Apply the Pythagorean formula to get its length as

$$2\sqrt{r^2-OC^2}=2\sqrt{9-5}=4$$

Comment: Can you please clarify from how did you get 2 from in 2sqrt(r^2 - OC^2)?

Comment: @DavidFoldi - OC bisects the chord. I added a diagram

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the line which goes through $$C(1,2)$$ is given by $$y=m(x-1)+2$$. Now you can calculate the length of the chord.